# router in react js no targetting a new page

Tags: reactjs

This is the login page from my navbar. As from navbar I used router and navlink to link to the new page. Similarly I tried to link my login page to signup page but the problem is the output comes on the same page and not on the new page.

[image: heres the image..sign up page comes afterlogin box]

below is the code

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Nav, Navbar} from 'react-bootstrap'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import Signup from './Signup';


export default class Login extends Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <br></br>
          <br></br>
          <br></br>
          <h2>LOGIN</h2>
          <br></br>

          <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css" />
          <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <div class="wrapper fadeInDown">
            <div id="formContent">
              <div class="fadeIn first">
                <div class="brand_logo_container">
                  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a3/15/41/a31541c5da1ccffdc1fd45cc4be670d3.png" class="brand_logo" alt="Logo" />                  </div>

              </div>
              <form>
                <input type="text" id="login" class="fadeIn second" name="login" placeholder="Login ID"></input>
                <input type="password" id="password" class="fadeIn third" name="login" placeholder="Password"></input>
                <input type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth" value="Log In"></input>
              </form>
                <div id="formFooter">
                  Don't have an account ?
                  <Nav className="me-auto my-2 my-lg-0">
                    <Nav.Link as={Link} to={"/signup"}>Sign up</Nav.Link>
                  </Nav>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/signup">
              <Signup />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: where did you define `<Route path="/login">` ? it seems you are defining `<Route path="/signup">` as a nested route of `login` page

Comment: I'd recommend taking a look at react-router tutorial, you may have missed it. https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial

Comment: the <Route path="/login"> in in the navbar.js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please put login component code inside `<Route>` too. Otherwise the login component code is going to render unconditionally.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Nav, Navbar} from 'react-bootstrap'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import Signup from './Signup';


export default class Login extends Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/signup">
              <Signup />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/login">
            <div>
          <br></br>
          <br></br>
          <br></br>
          <h2>LOGIN</h2>
          <br></br>

          <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css" />
          <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <div class="wrapper fadeInDown">
            <div id="formContent">
              <div class="fadeIn first">
                <div class="brand_logo_container">
                  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a3/15/41/a31541c5da1ccffdc1fd45cc4be670d3.png" class="brand_logo" alt="Logo" />                  </div>

              </div>
              <form>
                <input type="text" id="login" class="fadeIn second" name="login" placeholder="Login ID"></input>
                <input type="password" id="password" class="fadeIn third" name="login" placeholder="Password"></input>
                <input type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth" value="Log In"></input>
              </form>
                <div id="formFooter">
                  Don't have an account ?
                  <Nav className="me-auto my-2 my-lg-0">
                    <Nav.Link as={Link} to={"/signup"}>Sign up</Nav.Link>
                  </Nav>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks a ton..!!!...worked for me

Comment: Sure. Please consider upvoting the answer if it helped you :D

Answer (score -1):

try to use `<Link to={"/signup"}>Sign up</Link>` from react-router-dom instead of `<Nav.Link/>`

Comment: Even if that might be a good advice, this is not the cause of the issue